# Using a body class for divs inside that body

Tags: html, css

I have a class inside a body, for example:

```html
<body class="test">
```

And in this body are several HTML tags: section, div, footer, etc...

I would like to know if it is possible to use the body class for each div separately.

For example this would be the HTML code:

```html
<body class="test">
    <div id="article">
    </div>
</body>
```

And this would be the CSS code:

```css
.test #article {margin-left: 100px;}
```

Can this be done? Is this the correct way?

Comment: Why you want to wrap every div with body tag?

Comment: Yes. you can do that. But when using an id, you need not mention any selector for the parent (meaning `#article {margin-left: 100px;}` would suffice) since `id` values are supposed to be unique in an HTML Document.

Comment: http://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/tutorials/css-layout/structure/

Comment: You should use `classes` instead of `id` for css styling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `body` multiple times, if you are looking forward to do so, that's invalid HTML, a document can have only single `body` element.

But if you are talking about assigning `class` to your `body` tag, than that's fine, you can use `>` direct descendant selector with `element.class` selector if you are looking to select only direct element to `body` having an `id` of `#article`, also this will make your selector precise

```
body.test > #article {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

This way you will target an element having `id` of `#article` where documents `body` has a `class` of `.test`.

---

Also, just remember that id's are unique regardless of any element it is assigned to, so it will be better if you use `id` for the `body` tag, and if you are going to target more than one element nested inside the `body` than better use `classes` for those elements, so your selector can be written as

```
body#test > .article {
   margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be done to separate that CSS markup (with the specific body class) from other pages with different classes for body (or no class at all).

You can only have one body tag for each page (full html file or constructed from various parts).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should now that you can refer to basic html elements, such as header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, withouth making a class or id selector.

For instance:

html

```
<body>
    <div id="article">
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
body
{
   display: block;
}
```

So the final css would be like

```
body #article {margin-left: 100px;}
```

Your way is also correct.
What i would recommend to you is to either use classes or  ids
in order to simplify your code. Its not wrong if you don't do so, but it might confuse you sometimes.

Finally you should avoid using for ids or classes the name "article",since it is a basic element in html5